# Profile pictures hosted on imgur are broken in mobile view

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, profile-picture, imgur

I noticed that when using the mobile view (either on mobile device or from desktop computer) some avatars are broken, including my own, when inside question page. For example:

> [image]

Quick check show that Emmett's profile picture is taken from gravatar while my picture is hosted on imgur.

Going directly to the broken image URL gave this address: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/rH58B.png?s=30&g=1` and [as you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rH58B.png?s=30&g=1) (until fixed) this bring the following error page:

> Imgur is used to share photos with social networks and online communities, and has the funniest pictures from all over the Internet.
>
> ## Imgur ♥'s Stack Exchange
>
> This is a commercial Imgur installation for the Stack Exchange network. If you'd like your own setup similar to Stack Exchange's then feel free to contact Alan at alan@imgur.com. Otherwise, you're probably not supposed to be on this page...

Changing the "?s=30" to "?s=32" in the URL [fix the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rH58B.png?s=32&g=1).

Gravatar does not have such white list of allowed thumbnail size thus not affected.

Can this please be fixed by either changing the thumbnail size in mobile view to 32 as well, or adding "30" to imgur white list?

Comment: Ahhh, this explains a lot. I was wondering what was causing that, nice catch.

Comment: @Tim surprised you didn't check the source, usually you are one step before everyone else on those things. :-)

Comment: Heheh, I had noticed the problem on mobile but hadn't remembered to ever look into it more. :)

Comment: Related, but slightly odd: in chat [someone claims](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188384/bug-in-user-image-in-chat) that value `16` is problematic, but `18` is not? For me, from Amsterdam, both are fine though. So maybe it's not about the sizes, but just that one of the Imgur CDNs not working okay. (Ping @Geoff.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have emailed imgur regarding this size - they will fix it up soon.

Comment: I see they put default of 128 pixels in case of "unrecognised" value. I'm pretty sure that it's going to break *something*. :)