# bug in user image in chat

Tags: bug, chat, profile-picture

In chat certain users image is not showing correctly

> [image]

but when we change 16 to 18 in image src it just works fine

please let me know if its dup i tried but couldn't find

Comment: Not a dupe, but same cause: [Profile pictures hosted on imgur are broken in mobile view](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187969/profile-pictures-hosted-on-imgur-are-broken-in-mobile-view).

Comment: As an aside, http://i.stack.imgur.com/cJbY9.jpg?g&s=16 works fine for me, from Amsterdam.

Comment: @Arjan which browser are you using i am getting this resuly in chrome 27.0.1453.116

Comment: Same 27.0.1453.116 here, on a Mac. Maybe a problem on just one of Imgur's CDNs.